# Разбиение строки по символу с учетом экранирования (регулярка)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста, не могу регулярку придумать. Есть строка с разделителем (|). Нужно по нему поделить. Задача тревиальная, но нужно учесть возможность его экранирования. Экранированный разделитель разделителем не является =)
Например:

```
значение1|значение2\|значение 2.1|значение 3
```

Результат:

```
["значение 1", "значение2\|значение 2.1", "значение 3"]
```

Comment: А что значит "но нему поделить": захватить в группу все до разделителя или захватить сам разделитель, для последующего использования в функциях типа split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учетом возможного экранирования самих экранирующих символов (`\\`) выделение разделителей для функций типа [perl split](http://ideone.com/VFV57K) (php [preg_split](http://ideone.com/aD4T2o)):

```
/(?:[^\\]|[^\\](?:\\{2})+|^)\K\|/
```

Ищем такой разделитель перед которым стоит НЕ обратная косая или четное количество обратных косых или начало строки. Тест на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PedXcK/1)

Для захвата самих значений до разделителей (например для обработки в [цикле](http://ideone.com/O3ULln)):

```
/(?:[^|\\]+|\\.)+/
```

Тест на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rYNORh/1)

Расшифровка:

```
(?:                   # Не захватывающая группа
   [^|\\]+            # 1 и более символов НЕ | и НЕ \
  |\\.                # или любой символ после обратной косой
)+                    # группа может повторятся много раз
```

Comment: по поводу экранирования обратного слеша - хорошая идея =)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
/((?:[^\\|]|\\\|)+)/
```

т.е. захватываем все идущие подряд символы отличающиеся от `\` и `|` или захватываем `\|`

Пример тут https://regex101.com/r/SIptpB/1

**UPD**

С учетом одинарного `\`

```
/((?:[^\\|]|\\\||\\)+)/
```

Пример https://regex101.com/r/SIptpB/2